# Pasar a otro activity al dar click en RecyclerView

Tags: android-studio, firebase, recyclerview

Buenas, estoy trabajando con un `RecyclerView` y una `barra de buscar` en `Android Studio` con `Firebase`, mi barra de buscar si funciona pero lo que trato de hacer es que al momento de dar click en una opcion del `RecyclerView` se mande a otro `activity` diferente a otro(dependiendo la opción que escogió).
Mi código es el siguiente.

Esta parte es del `Activity` donde se muestra todo(la `barra de buscar`, `recyclerview`).

```
public class SearchBarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//-------------------
EditText buscar_texto;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
//--
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
//--
ArrayList<String> nombresList;
ArrayList<String> nombreusuarioList;
ArrayList<String> fotoperfilList;
SearchAdapter searchAdapter;
//---------------------

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_bar);
    //----------------------------------------------
    buscar_texto= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.buscar_texto);
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    //--------------
    databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    firebaseUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    //--------------
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    //--------------
    nombresList=new ArrayList<>();
    nombreusuarioList=new ArrayList<>();
    fotoperfilList=new ArrayList<>();
    //-----------------------------------------------
    buscar_texto.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                setAdapter(s.toString());
            }else {
                nombresList.clear();
                nombreusuarioList.clear();
                fotoperfilList.clear();
                recyclerView.removeAllViews();
            }
        }
    });
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
private void setAdapter(final String searchedString) {
    databaseReference.child("usuarios").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            nombresList.clear();
            nombreusuarioList.clear();
            fotoperfilList.clear();
            recyclerView.removeAllViews();

            int counter = 0;

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String uid = snapshot.getKey();
                String nombres = snapshot.child("nombres").getValue(String.class);
                String nombreusuario = snapshot.child("nombreusuario").getValue(String.class);
                String foto_perfil = snapshot.child("foto_perfil").getValue(String.class);

                if (nombres.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())){
                    nombresList.add(nombres);
                    nombreusuarioList.add(nombreusuario);
                    fotoperfilList.add(foto_perfil);
                    counter++;
                }else if (nombreusuario.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())){
                    nombresList.add(nombres);
                    nombreusuarioList.add(nombreusuario);
                    fotoperfilList.add(foto_perfil);
                    counter++;
                }
                if (counter == 15)
                    break;
            }

            searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(SearchBarActivity.this,nombresList,nombreusuarioList,fotoperfilList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Este clase es la parte del `SearchAdapter` que se muestra arriba

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder> {
Context context;
ArrayList<String> nombresList;
ArrayList<String> nombreusuarioList;
ArrayList<String> fotoperfilList;

class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView foto_perfil;
    TextView nombres,nombreusuario;

    public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        foto_perfil = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fotoperfil);
        nombres = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombres);
        nombreusuario=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreusuario);
    }
}

public SearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> nombresList, ArrayList<String> nombreusuarioList, ArrayList<String> fotoperfilList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.nombresList = nombresList;
    this.nombreusuarioList = nombreusuarioList;
    this.fotoperfilList = fotoperfilList;
}

@Override
public SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.search_list_items,parent, false);
    return new SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.nombres.setText(nombresList.get(position));
    holder.nombreusuario.setText(nombreusuarioList.get(position));

    Glide.with(context).load(fotoperfilList.get(position)).asBitmap().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round).into(holder.foto_perfil);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return nombresList.size();
}
}
```

activity_search_bar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

search_list_items

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi base de datos en firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @kevvelas asigna el listener OnClickListener a holder.itemView!

Answer (score 1):

Una manera de hacer esto es agregar un `onClickListener` al view del `SearchViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.nombres.setText(nombresList.get(position));
    holder.nombreusuario.setText(nombreusuarioList.get(position));
    holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openActivity();
        }
    });
}

public void openActivity() {
    // ... agrega aqui el codigo para abrir la activity
}
```

Comentario a parte: recomendaría crear un POJO usuario y que el adapter utilice una única lista de objetos de tipo Usuario. De otra manera es más complicado tratar cada array list por separado.
Además, si ese Usuario es serializable o parcelable, es más sencillo pasarlo como argumento a la activity en un bundle, en lugar de utilizar cada atributo por separado, lo cual te obliga a mapearlos cada vez.
Una manera sencilla de hacer esto es usar `getValue(Usuario.class)` en lugar de manualmente obtener cada atributo.
Más sobre esto en la documentación: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: ah ok, pero como seria el código para pasar a la siguiente actividad?; con un intent?

Comment: Sí, con un intent https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score -1):

Debe ser asignando el listener `OnClickListener` a `holder.itemView` y dentro agregar el lanzamiento de una nueva `Activity` mediante un `Intent`:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.nombres.setText(nombresList.get(position));
        holder.nombreusuario.setText(nombreusuarioList.get(position));

        //* Agrega listener.
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {

               //* Inicia otra Activity.

               Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, OtraActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);

             }
         });

Glide.with(context).load(fotoperfilList.get(position)).asBitmap().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round).into(holder.foto_perfil);
    }
```